# Azure function c# .net throws 502

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, appinsights

I am having consumption plan in azure, do not have any gateway or proxy setup.

While testing I got this error also its not logging in my app insights, it neglects that request, as like it did not reached/requested to it.
How can fix this ?

```
502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server
```

Comment: Consumption plan -- consumption plan which Scale out automatically, even during periods of high load.
It has Max instances - 200, Max outbound connections (per instance) 600 active (1200 total), Max memory (GB per instance) 1.5, I am not using more than 20% of them. 
So there is no issue of "application using high memory/CPU"

Comment: "requests taking a long time" - it has lot of instances free, it will definitely not going to wait long for execution as per doc.
 If its getting requested and taking long time in execution why I cannot see any logs for that request? 
"application crashing due to an exception" 
Same thing again is the request even executing (no logs) ?

Comment: Hi, can you offer the settings when you created the function app? I will try that, maybe I can reproduce.

Comment: It the default setting I haven't changed anything. I even tried by creating the new repo and function app in azure still that problem exists.

Answer (score -1):

**Cause:**

This problem is often caused by application level issues, such as:

1.requests taking a long time

2.application using high memory/CPU

3.application crashing due to an exception.

**Steps:**

1.Observe and monitor application behavior

2.Collect data

3.Mitigate the issue

Have a look of this [Offcial doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-http-502-http-503).